# Running AppleTV apps without a external server

Tags: apple-tv, tvml, tvos10

We have a simple apple tv app that is basically a static ad. Our apple tv is the latest (4th gen, tvOS 10.0.1). The problem is ***we do not have an external server!!!*** so how can we by pass the lines below or make it point to a local application.js file:

```
static let tvBaseURL = "http://localhost:9001"
static let tvBootURL = "\(AppDelegate.tvBaseURL)/application.js"
```

Are we ***required*** to have a server for developing apple tv apps? We have seen other examples on stack on how to do this but they are outdated and/or for older devices. Any help would be appreciated. It's either we get this working or go back to AndroidTV

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use external server in tvOS apps (even for the latest tvOS 10). You can use `UIKit` like in iOS applications to build application without JavaScript. Also, you can create hybrid application (Swift+JavaScript) where external server is also not required.